Cytoscape.js error: can not create edge with unspecified source
In my angular js project I'm trying to use cytoscape.js library to build a graph and display it on one of my pages and so I have the following function that is being called when I navigate to the relevant page:
function init() {
   vm.loading = true;

   projectService.getNavigationTree({ projectLocationId: vm.id })
      .then(function (result) {
         var data = initNavigationTreeData(result.data);
         var nodes = buildNodes(data);
         var edges = buildEdges(data);

         edges.forEach(function (elem) {
            var isFound = _.find(data, { id: elem.source });
            if (!isFound)
               console.log(elem);
            else
               console.log("true");
         });

         vm.cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),

            elements: {
               nodes: nodes,
               edges: edges
            },

            layout: {
               name: 'random',
               fit: true,
               padding: 50
            },

            style: [
                {
                   selector: 'node',
                   style: {
                      'label': 'data(text)'
                   }
                }
            ]
         });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log("error = ", error.message);
      })
      .finally(function () {
         vm.loading = false;
      });
}

Here are my buildNodes and buildEdges function:
function buildNodes(data) {
   var nodes = [];

   data.forEach(function (elem) {
      var node = { data: elem };
      nodes.push(node);
   });

   return nodes;
}

function buildEdges(data) {
   var edges = [];

   data.forEach(function (elem) {
      if (elem.parentId) {
         var edge = { id: elem.parentId + ' ' + elem.id, source: elem.parentId, target: elem.id };
         edges.push(edge);
      }
   });

   return edges;
}

Here is the initNavigationTreeData function (in case it's relevant):
function initNavigationTreeData(navigationTreeData) {
   var treeData = _.map(navigationTreeData, function (item) {
      return {
         id: item.id,
         rawId: item.rawId,
         text: item.name,
         fullPath: item.fullPath,
         parentId: item.parentId ? item.parentId : null,
         isSelectable: item.isSelectable
      };
   });

   return treeData;
}

And here's the error I'm getting:

I can't understand why there's such an error, even though in my edges.forEach whose purpose is to make sure that all my edges have a source which they do (since its always returning true)
Note: if instead of
elements: {
   nodes: nodes,
   edges: edges
}, 

I replace it with
elements: {
   nodes: nodes
}, 

then it will work and all the nodes will show up on my screen

In your case, while adding edges you set the source as elem.parentId, but there may not be a node in your data whose id is equal to elem.parentId. In other words, let's say you have nodes n1 = {id: 'n1', parentId: 'parent1'} and n2 = {id: 'n2', parentId: 'parent2'}. While adding an edge you check if n1 has a parentId. Yes, it has a parentId but there is no node with id equal to "parent1" to be a source.
